# How to limit number of diff lines shown in gitk?

Tags: diff, gitk

Looking for an option/workaround to limit the diff content (shown in the bottom panel) for any particular file (e.g. to first N lines only), as the patch/diff may be too big and causes the GUI to freeze. I did try the different options accepted by `git diff`, but don't see any way to pass them to `gitk` (unlike `git-gui`). Note that limiting the number of lines of context does not work since the diff will still be shown with zero context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change gitk's source code. It's one big Tcl/Tk file you can edit directly or make a copy of. It's location may depend on your operating system. If you are on linux or macos it's probably `/usr/bin/gitk` or `/usr/local/bin/gitk`.

Inside the procedure `diffcmd`, change this line:

`set cmd [concat | git diff-tree -r $flags $ids]`

You could add `diff-tree` arguments, or simply pipe the diff output to another program, like `head`:

`set cmd [concat | git diff-tree -r $flags $ids | head -n500]`

This applies to the complete diff, not just to one file.